# Working on Same Firebase Account from Different Android Studio (Different PC)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want my friend to design login registration page in his Android Studio, and I will do the rest of the work of real time database handling on mine... we are using Firebase as a database.

What can we do so that we both alter the same database (Firebase) from different PCs?

When we finish, we are going to combine it together..

How can we do that??
Should we keep package name the same or should copy same json file in our app folder?

Answer (score 1):

Well I suggest you to upload your project on GitHub and tell your friend to take the clone of your project from GitHub and they will be able to work on the same code. And you no need to add any further more JSON file, as you both will be working on the same project code from your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how to use [Version Control (VCS)](https://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/) to manage your projects. The rest is pretty straight forward, you want to push your project to your desired branch on your VCS then just have your friend open up Android Studio on their machine and instead of clicking 'Start a new Android Studio project' have them select 'Check out project from Version Control'. It should create a clone of the project that is on version control and they can do that from there. Make sure they commits and pushes their changes (`CTRL+K`) to version control so you can then retrieve the project**. About using Firebase that won't matter they can still connect to the same account.

*** To retrieve the project or update it on your machine you open up your copy that is linked to VCS and press `CTRL+T` or alternatively go to the VCS window and you should see VCS with a blue arrow facing down with the words 'Update Project...'*

Comment: Will try both approaches.